# Need help with finding a matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

Could anyone please help me find a 4 by 4 matrix `A` such that `A.Transpose[A]` exactly equals the following matrix:

```
{{1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2}, 
{-(1/2), 1, 1/2, 0}, 
{0, 1/2, 1, -(1/2)}, 
{1/2, 0, -(1/2), 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
B = {{1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1, 1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2, 1, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0, -(1/2), 1}};
{λ, U} = Eigensystem[B];
A = Transpose[Sqrt[λ] Normalize /@ U];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the numerical solution. Could you please find A such that A.Transpose[A] exactly equals the given matrix? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the updated post.

Comment: Thank you for your update. Woud it be unique up to multiplications by orthogonal matrices? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "multiplications by orthogonal matrices". Since the eigenvalue $1$ is two-fold, the matrix $A$ is _not_ unique up to multiplication by orthogonal matrices from the right, because one can also rotate within the eigenspace of the eigenvalue 1 by multiplying, e.g., `RotationMatrix[{U[[2]], U[[3]]}]` from the left.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the problem has a unique solution without imposing any restriction on the solution $A$. If we assume that the matrix $A$ is symmetric (i.e. $A=A^T$), the solution ($AA=B$) can be easily obtained by the singular value decomposition (SVD) method.

Essentially, SVD decomposes the square matrix $B$ into the form of $B=U\Lambda U^T$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix and the matrix $U$ is unitary (i.e. $U^TU=UU^T=I$). Observing that $B=U\sqrt\Lambda U^T (U\sqrt\Lambda U^T)$, we have $A=U\sqrt\Lambda U^T$.

In Mathematica,

```
    matA = Module[{
       matB = {{1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1, 1/2, 0}, 
               {0, 1/2, 1, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0, -(1/2), 1}},
       u, \[Lambda], v
       },

      (* Calculate the singular value decomposition *)
      {u, \[Lambda], v} = SingularValueDecomposition[matB];

      (* Calculate the matrix A *)
      u.Sqrt[w].Transpose[u] // Simplify
      ]
```

Comment: The matrix $A$ is definitely not unique as one may multiply it from the right by any orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

The Cholesky decomposition can be used for this (objections from the usual suspects notwithstanding). It can be applied to any symmetric real-valued positive definite matrix, that is, any symmetric matrix with positive eigenvalues. Is that the case here?

```
mat = {{1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2}, {-(1/2), 1, 1/2, 0},
{0, 1/2, 1, -(1/2)}, {1/2, 0, -(1/2), 1}};
Eigenvalues[mat]

(* Out[62]= {2, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

Okay, so one of them is zero. In such circumstances one can perturb by adding a "small" value to the main diagonal, take the Cholesky decomposition, and extract the limiting value as that perturbation goes to zero from above.

```
matmod = mat + DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[eps, 4]];
cd = Simplify[CholeskyDecomposition[matmod], Assumptions -> eps > 0]

(* Out[68]= {{Sqrt[1 + eps], -(1/(2 Sqrt[1 + eps])), 0, 1/(
  2 Sqrt[1 + eps])}, {0, Sqrt[(3 + 8 eps + 4 eps^2)/(4 + 4 eps)], 
  Sqrt[(1 + eps)/(3 + 8 eps + 4 eps^2)], 1/(
  2 Sqrt[(1 + eps) (3 + 8 eps + 4 eps^2)])}, {0, 0, Sqrt[
  1 + eps - (1 + eps)/(3 + 8 eps + 4 eps^2)], -((Sqrt[2] (1 + eps)^2)/
   Sqrt[(3 + 8 eps + 4 eps^2) (1 + 5 eps + 6 eps^2 + 2 eps^3)])}, {0, 
  0, 0, Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(eps (1 + eps) (2 + eps))/(
   1 + 4 eps + 2 eps^2)]}} *)
```

Now take the limit: and check the result.

```
lmat = Limit[cd, eps -> 0, Direction -> -1]
Transpose[lmat].lmat == mat

(* Out[75]= {{1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2},
{0, Sqrt[3]/2, 1/Sqrt[3], 1/(2 Sqrt[3])},
{0, 0, Sqrt[2/3], -Sqrt[(2/3)]}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}

Out[76]= True *)
```

This case actually could have been handled more simply. Instead of using a symbolic `eps` one can use an explicit positive value, say `E`. Take the decomposition and then replace with `E->0`. It works.

Comment: Time for an $LDL^T$-decomposition in _Mathematica_? (IMHO, it's overdue.)  ;)